# What is the difference between xtype and alias?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

What is the difference between xtype and alias used in Sencha? They're both seem to be used as shorthand in different places.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is really confusing, even Sencha Touch developers team does not have a common opinion.

As far as I know, they design this merely for performance. `Alias` appears earlier than `xtype`, they create `xtype` config because if we don't have to parse the string to get the xtype like before, it's faster.

Anyway, things like `xtype`, `ptype`, `ltype` or most common, `alias` should be unified and clarified in next releases, said the dev team.

Comment: Looks like they did not :(

Comment: I used to work for Sencha, I can assure you that the Sencha Touch team has never said this. The difference between alias and xtype is quite clear, and is reflected in the documentation.

Comment: it's been long since this answer was posted. I didn't even remember which thread I joined on sencha forum, but it MIGHT be this one: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?150577-Ext.define-xtype-vs-alias

Answer (score 20):

When you use "alias" to declare an xtype, you have to preface it with "widget".

Example:

```
{
   ...
   alias: 'widget.mycomponent'
   ...
}
```

When you use the xtype property, you can leave the "widget." part off, because that part is assumed:

Example:

```
{
   ...
   xtype: 'mycomponent'
   ...
}
```

The reason for the two different properties is because you can declare aliases of things other than "widget", like alias: 'layout.card', which is used in the framework. However, for end-user code that reference view objects, you'll probably be using either

```
alias: 'widget.mycomponent'
```

or

```
xtype: 'mycomponent'
```