# Sencha: what does terms xtype, ltype, ptype, alias means also what is dockedItem?

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

Learning sencha these days, few terms are really confusing, googled but could not find exact meaning of these terms

Thanks in advance!![this link should have described xtype  http://www.sencha.com/learn/ext-js-4-panel-docked-items/](http://www.sencha.com/learn/ext-js-4-panel-docked-items/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some useful links, that might solve your problem.

1. Difference between alias and xtype, ltype, ptype:
   [What is the difference between xtype and alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145460/what-is-the-difference-between-xtype-and-alias)
2. Overview of Sencha Touch:
   http://tobyho.com/2010/09/17/sencha-touch-overview/

I hope this helps.